# How to have jQuery.ajax cover both error() & complete() in single clause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a slideshow that uses an ajax call to fetch my data like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    timeout:8000,
    url:    full_fallback_uri,
    success: function(result) {
        //do stuff
    }, 
    error: function() {
        self.skip();
    }, 
    complete: function(xhr, data) {
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            self.skip();
        }
    },                      
    asynch: false,
});
```

So in case the ajax call fails, skip() is called in order to skip current slide.

Now above setup doesn't work, since in the case of an error, skip() is called twice, causing a double-skip (skipping two slides not just the current one).

And if I leave out either the 
    error()
or the
    complete() (with the check for http status != 200)
it's not enough, the one doesn't cover all possible errors.

How could I write a clause that covers both error and complete cases?

Would something like this work?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    timeout:8000,
    url:    full_fallback_uri,
    success: function(result) {
        //do stuff
    }, 
    error: function() {
        this.myErrorSign = true; //DEFINING MY OWN VARIABLE ON THIS jQuery.ajax object
        this.complete(); //MANUALLY CALL THE COMPLETE FUNCTION, IN CASE THIS ISN'T DONE AUTOMATICALLY UPON FAIL
    }, 
    complete: function(xhr, data) {
        if (xhr.status != 200 || this.myErrorSign == true) { //LOOK NOT ONLY FOR STS!=200 BUT ALSO FOR THE VARIABLE THAT WAS DEFINED IN THE ERROR CASE ABOVE
            self.skip();
        }
    },                      
    asynch: false,
});
```

Or perhaps this design will be similarly flawed, and in some cases call the skip() twice just as well?

Comment: So you're obviously expecting a lot of errors in the code you're writing ?

Comment: it's kind of an API so I don't have full control.

Comment: I don't really know what you're doing, but I can already tell that whatever it is you're doing it wrong. The error handler will always fire on errors, what error could you possibly encounter where the statuscode isn't 200 and the error handler wasn't called ?

Comment: I run this on my localhost with internet cable disconnected and nothing happens (no complete() and no always(). Perhaps I defined it wrong...

Comment: Yes, you must have defined it wrong. always and complete always get triggered, unless you return false in beforesend.

Comment: And it's `async`, not `asynch`, and you shouldn't be using that **at all**, leave it alone, **DO NOT** set it to false !!!

Comment: @MattiasSvensson On the side note, the methods you're using are deprecated: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following simple logic and you cannot go wrong - you are quite close.

1. The `error` callback **always fires (whenever it does) before** the `complete` callback. Have a variable that can be seen by both callbacks, say `error = false;` initially set to `false` before the ajax call.
2. In the `error` callback set `error = true;` that's it.
3. In the `complete` callback - **this callback always fires** - use the following:

   `if( error || (xhr.status != 200) ) {
       self.skip();
   } 
   //done ... you may want to have a way to reset error = false before a re-run`

Please note that `this` within each callback points to the callback function and is therefore local ... have a variable with a wider scope ... outside of the ajax call. Since the `complete` callback fires on error and on success, you do not need to call it explicitly. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could **only** `.always` and differ wether the arguments come from an error or not:

```
var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
    /* only settings, no callbacks, no error: fn(){}! */
});

ajaxRequest.always(function (jqXhr, statusText) {
    // gets called on complete and on error
    if (statusText === 'error') {
        skip();
    }
});
```

Works on my local machine, when called server is down.

Check out [jQuerys documentation on that](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: `always === complete`

Comment: @adeneo Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: I guess, I wasnt too clear about, what I meant. Updated my answer.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen - That's great, but suggesting using `always` over `complete` makes no sense as they do exactly the same thing. `fail` and `always` uses the promise interface, but they fire on the exact same things as `complete` and `error`, there's no difference in when they would actually execute the callback.

Comment: `always` inherits from deferred.always. What it does is [Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)

Comment: @adeneo I wasn't suggesting that `.always()` and `.complete()` are different. The only thing I'm pointing out is that the jQuery team recommends you should use `.always()` **instead of** `.complete()` since the latter is deprecated. So I guess you don't have a choice; in the near future `.always()` is the only thing you have left.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen - and how does that solve the OP's question today? If it doesn't work with `complete`, why would it work with `always` ?

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer the OP's question, I'm commenting with related information. @juk Partly answers the OP's question by showing an example of a callback that's always called, in all situations (error and success); something the OP is asking for.

Comment: he should **only** use the `always` method. he should **not** set his `error` callback.

Comment: This almost did the trick, I had to add the error handler from user3558931 below as well for it to work. Could be that Chrome & MAMP has an odd behaviour... I have had that before..